# Ubuntu Install — Unallocated space doesn't show

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I have been trying to install Ubuntu as dual boot with long standing Windows 10 on my laptop

There are two drives on my notebook: one is a 128GB SSD that I use only for Windows, and the other is a 500GB HDD to store all of my data.

I want to install Ubuntu on the HDD and tried to shrink the volume for Ubuntu with Windows's disk management tool, but the unallocated space not recognized by Ubuntu installer. I see this warning:

[image: warning]

I have tried to create unallocated space from gparted but the problem still occurs. Also tried to “googlefu” my problem. A lot of posts said I need to convert my disk from dynamic to basic but my disks are already set as basic:

[image: basic]

Comment: Even in your Windows screenshot, no unallocated space appears. So obviously, also the installer won't find it. For performance, I strongly recommend to install Ubuntu on SSD as well, and use HDD for data storage.

Comment: @vanadium oh right i forgot to add, the unallocated space even tho created in disk management tool it doesn't recognized it, but it recognized it by tool like minitool partition wizard

Comment: It sounds like you have managed to resize the filesystem and not the partition. Minitool partition wizard claims to be able to do that but I’m not familiar with it. As long as you have good data backups I suggest you try to resize the partition with minitool

Comment: @PonJar i did resizing with minitool partition but the the problem still exist

Comment: You might get better help on a Windows forum since this is a problem with an NTFS partition. However a couple of thoughts. Does minitool have an apply step like GParted. You may have specified what your changes but not applied them. No one can help you unless you describe what you did and what the outcome was. Just saying you still have the problem gives us nothing to go on. If you resized the partition how big is it now and how large is the filesystem. Add this to your question if you want more help here.